# How to resolve Forbidden 403 error when making a urllib request with POST data in Django using Docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, urllib

I have a three layer Django project that uses Docker. The first container is the front end and does all of the rendering, the second layer deals with logic for what to display on the front end and interacts with the database layer (third) by requesting JSON, and the third container/layer interacts directly with the database.

I have a form in the front end where a user tries to sign up. However, when I make an API call to my second layer using POST and passing the form values, I keep receiving a 403 Forbidden Error. I am using a CSRF token in my form. How can I remove the 403 Forbidden Error?

Some code in my views.py at the front end level:

```
def signup(request):
      #more code
      username = form.cleaned_data["username"] 
      #and some more fields
      data = {"username": username, "password":password, ... "location": location}
      postData = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
      try:
         req = urllib.request.Request("url to API in 2nd layer", postData)
      #more code
```

Django attempts to execute the try statement, but I am getting a 403 Forbidden Error.

Comment: what is your "url to API in 2nd layer" looks like ? they are on the same docker host?

Comment: They are linked using docker compose. There is no issue when I access that link with a GET request. But I am getting a 403 Forbidden error with a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow CORS calls in your 2nd Django project

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

.....

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

.....

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Here is the referenced lib. [Django-CORS-Headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)